# Coding Fibonacci in python. Got errors

Tags: python, list, fibonacci

There is a assigment I am doing for Beginners in AI and Python.

Create a Class NewInt that inherits from int. It should have an Instance Method is_fibonacci () that returns True if the number is a Fibonacci number, False if not. Generate a list with NewInt from 0 to 1000. Then create a List Comprehension that only retains the numbers that are Fibonacci using the class and instance method you created.

[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987] #Expected output for task

I made this code for the task

```
import math

class NewInt(int):
   
    def is_Perfect_Square(x):
        s = int(math.sqrt(x))
        return s*s == x

    def is_fibonacci(n):

        return is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n + 4) or is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n - 4)

    fibonacci_List = [i for i in range(0,1000)if NewInt().is_fibonacci(i)]
    print(fibonacci_List)
```

It worked few hours ago, but i get errors like this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-377e0f9b7814> in <module>
      1 import math
      2 
----> 3 class NewInt(int):
      4 
      5     def is_Perfect_Square(x):

<ipython-input-8-377e0f9b7814> in NewInt()
     11         return is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n + 4) or is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n - 4)
     12 
---> 13     fibonacci_List = [i for i in range(0,1000)if NewInt().is_fibonacci(i)]
     14     print(fibonacci_List)

<ipython-input-8-377e0f9b7814> in <listcomp>(.0)
     11         return is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n + 4) or is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n - 4)
     12 
---> 13     fibonacci_List = [i for i in range(0,1000)if NewInt().is_fibonacci(i)]
     14     print(fibonacci_List)

TypeError: is_fibonacci() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can someone help me point out my mistakes? I am new to Python.

Comment: You are somewhat confusing instance and static methods here. You can try `NewInt.is_fibonacci(i)`, but the whole `NewInt` class does not make all that much sense. Also, why not just generate the fibonacci sequence instead of testing each number whether it is a fibonacci number?

Comment: Indentation is incorrect in your code.

Comment: Your class methods need a first argument of `self` to contain the instance reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is pythons OOP concept

  `NewInt().is_fibonacci(i)`
- When the above method is called python internally does this

  `NewInt().is_fibonacci(self, i)`
- self refers to the object that invoked the method in this case `NewInt()`
- But in the class definition the method is defined for only one parameter hence

> TypeError: is_fibonacci() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
import math

class NewInt(int):

    def is_Perfect_Square(self, x):
        s = int(math.sqrt(x))
        return s*s == x

    def is_fibonacci(self, n):
        return self.is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n + 4) or self.is_Perfect_Square(5*n*n - 4)

fibonacci_List = [i for i in range(0,1000)if NewInt().is_fibonacci(i)]
print(fibonacci_List)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math


class NewInt(int):

    # In my opinion you should make a constructor
    def __init__(self, number):
        # Declare the attributes
        self.number = number

    def is_Perfect_Square(self):
        # Use that attribute which u have initialised already.
        x = self.number
        s = int(math.sqrt(x))
        return s * s == x

    def is_fibonacci(self):
        n = self.number
        # Create an instance of your class each time u wanna access a method
        # e.g. NewInt(1234) creates an instant of the class NewInt. When you do this, u invoke the init method and that number attribute is intialised.
        return NewInt(5*n*n + 4).is_Perfect_Square() or NewInt(5 * n * n - 4).is_Perfect_Square()


fibonacci_List = [i for i in range(0, 1000) if NewInt(i).is_fibonacci()]

print(fibonacci_List)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987]
```

If you are always taking the value in the formal parameter of your function, it doesn't make sense to have a class.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nothing special. It's nice to get advice. I cool to see there is severals way to solve this problem. :)